# Can't make a fetch in IE9 once page is loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, internet-explorer-9

I have a site that is running in Node and using express for the server. I also have an API on a different server I need to hit. Everything works fine except in IE9. The issue is when ever i try to hit my API once i have the page loaded it breaks.

For example on the home page i have a search form where each step makes an API fetch and once I try to make my first fetch i get this error

```
"Unhanded promise rejectionError: Access Denied"
```

It seems like it has to do with a CORS issue since IE9 didnt have CORS and the era of the error message. Also when I make the fetched server side I have no issue, its just when the client tries to perform them.

Has anyone had an issue like this and if so how did you fix it?

Currently I am trying this but it hasnt worked yet:

First I changed my api host address to the current sites address with /api at the end.

```
    apiHost: process.env.API_HOST || 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api'
```

Then in my express server is run this:

```
app.use(modRewrite([`^/api/(.*)$ http://api.mysite.dev:8080/$1 [P]`]));
```

I was hoping to avoid making a fetch cross address with this but no luck as of yet.

Any help would be much appreciated

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I changed my host file for my machine to use mysite.dev for the 127.0.0.1 IP. Then went to mysite.dev rather than 127.0.0.1 when testing my site. Then did what I did above to get it to work